# Creating a private Git server on macOS 10.13 and Xcode 9

Tags: xcode, git

I am running a private Git server on my Mac Mini server. I upgraded the Mac Mini server to 10.13 High Sierra / Server 5.4 / Xcode 9 without first reading the small print.  I now I've lost the functionality on the Git server - that is central to my work flow.

Is there something I've missed here?  Can I get the Git server running again after the High Sierra upgrade - or do I have to wipe my machine and reinstall Sierra?

Comment: Your username checks out, I guess.

Comment: Not quite - I should have called myself BrownPaperBag, since that's the kind of mistake that I seem to be best at making.

Comment: Please provide some more context and the exact errors you are getting.  What type of software is running the private Git server?  Which version is it?  Is there a specific reference that you are talking about when you say "reading the small print" where something says this is incompatible?  When you try to start the server, what happens?  Etc.

Comment: I have just had the same issue. Using Sierra there was an option for an Xcode server which has disappeared in High Sierra. So there arent any errors, but rather an entirely missing feature. I believe Headbanger is trying to ask if it has been moved somewhere else, and if so how to find it. I would also be interested to know.

Comment: Okay - in the end I fixed it by creating a new user for git, generating new ssh keys, creating empty repositories in the git user account and then pushing everything over fresh. Not a massively difficult task, I admit, but given that it all just worked before I’m at a loss to see why they removed it now. I am disappoint. But never mind - I’m working again now.